# i keep recieving WSGi error when trying o deploy my django application to pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, deployment, wsgi, pythonanywhere

[MY pythonanywhere error log details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4afE.png)

This is my error log file, i have been stucked on this for four day now, please someone help...

Comment: It says it couldn't find "mysite" app inside your project. Maybe `__init__.py` file is missing in mysite folder, or you may didn't put `"mysite",` into `INSTALLED_APPS`list in settings.py

Comment: Oh thanks for the feedback, i gave up trying to serve the file from github, just had to do it from pythonanywhere platform